# knives, how long a blade should I carry?

Tags: safety, knives

what size of knife should I carry to not make peoples eyebrows raise? what manufacturers would you suggest?

Comment: are you hiking, camping, sailing, climbing? Where? Is the knife for slicing cheese and salami? Rope? Firewood? What criteria other than "people's eyebrows" apply here? Also, look through other questions in the knives tag to see if the information you want is already there.

Comment: Just like to know what the groups will put up with on hikes or trips in the Canadian bush and what size people have found the most useful for cutting saplings, cooking, starting fires and such.

Comment: @busher I'm from the Canadian bush. Unless you're in a park most people carry a shotgun, they won't look twice at your knife except to admire it. I used to carry a machete on the side of my pack everywhere I went. If I want to draw attention to myself I carry my [Western Bowie](https://www.google.ca/search?q=western+bowie+knife&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1652&bih=808&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI3bCdkvqQyAIVS5aICh0p9Ao8) on my hip.

Comment: Related: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/4448/2303

Comment: While I think we can allow *"what size of knife should I carry to not make peoples eyebrows raise?"* if framed in more practical way. But definitely not allowing *"what manufacturers would you suggest?"*.

Comment: @ShemSeger: Machete? :O Shotguns? :O

Comment: @WedaPashi Few people hike in the woods outside of parks without carrying lethal bear protection. Especially this year, there have been many bear attacks this year already. The Machete was mostly for clearing trails.

Comment: Oh, so different ways to go about it. We in India, usually do not carry anything for protection from bears and leopards, and we do not carry Machete or similar thing to clear the trails.

Answer (score 3):

For backpacking I use a small razor blade to open packages. Trail Design [Ultralight Knife](http://www.traildesigns.com/accessories/ultralight-knife) works just fine although it sometimes poke my fingers when reaching for it in my pocket.

Sometimes I carry a slightly bigger folding knife. What I usually miss the most is a good spreading knife for cheese / [Nutella](http://www.nutellausa.com/).